# Cannot find Passfilt.dll on 2008 DC

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, password, password-policy

I am trying to locate the standard password filter program called passfilt.dll on my 2008 DC.  I searched the whole C drive but I could not find it.
According to documentation, it should be in c:\windows\system32

Does anyone know where it is located?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen this?: https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/SecMgmt/installing-and-registering-a-password-filter-dll

Comment: I was under the impression the default password complexity policy was stored in a file called passfilt.dll but I could not find it.
I was just trying to find the file.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a separate password filter dll included with Windows. If you want password complexity functionality that is different from the default, you need to build/register your own custom dll. Or purchase a third party password filter.

Comment: I was under the impression the default password complexity policy was stored in a file called passfilt.dll but I could not find it. I was just trying to find the file.

Comment: @JLee: There was a separate file. 20 years ago on Windows NT 4.0.